# Generation 1 vs Generation 2 Azure VM same as VM (Classic) vs VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ausoemteam/2015/04/21/deciding-when-to-use-generation-1-or-generation-2-virtual-machines-with-hyper-v/
I want to create Gen2 VM in Azure.
 If i create VM using Virtual machine option, by default Gen2 machines would be created?

Am i correct?

[image: zu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not the same thing. Gen 1 vs Gen 2 is related to the VHD type you can deploy in Azure. Everything is always deployed as a Gen 1 in Azure. That being said, we now have Gen 2 VHDs in preview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/generation-2